# Customize Label, TextBox and RequiredFieldValidator Web Control problem on rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a customize web control with the combination of a Label, TextBox and RequiredFieldValidator. To done this, I create a class Field that inherit a Table Control.

```
namespace WebHRIS.Controls
{
    public class Field : Table
    {
        private Label lblField;
        private TextBox tbField;
        private RequiredFieldValidator rfvField;
        private string _text;
        private string _invalidMessage;
        private string _clientScript;
        private string _controlID;

        public virtual string LabelText
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }

        public virtual string InvalidMessage
        {
            get { return _invalidMessage; }
            set { _invalidMessage = value; }
        }

        public virtual string ClientScript
        {
            get { return _clientScript; }
            set { _clientScript = value; }
        }

        public virtual string ControlID
        {
            get { return _controlID; }
            set { _controlID = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            lblField = new Label();
            lblField.Text = _text;
            tc.Controls.Add(lblField);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tbField = new TextBox();
            tbField.ID = _controlID + this.ID;
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Controls.Add(tbField);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            rfvField = new RequiredFieldValidator();
            rfvField.ControlToValidate = tbField.ID;
            rfvField.ErrorMessage = this.InvalidMessage;
            rfvField.EnableClientScript = (this.ClientScript.ToLower() != "false");
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Controls.Add(rfvField);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            this.Rows.Add(tr);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(writer);
            lblField.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I used this control

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="udc" Namespace="WebHRIS.Controls" Assembly="WebHRIS" %>
<udc:Field ID="fSample" runat="server" LabelText="Sample : " InvalidMessage="ErrorMessage"
                                        ClientScript="false" ControlID="tb" />
```

Note that this is only a partial code. Now, I'm having a problem like this. [image]

I want to eliminate the 'Sample : ' text. T.I.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, I think you're getting the second line of text in you Render method:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    lblField.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

lblField is the Label control - I would bet that the Label is getting written a second time by the call to `lblField.RenderControl(writer)`.  Try removing that line and see if your control will render properly.

Comment: Thanks... your a life saver. =)